# -bash: command not found

Tags: linux, bash

I have little experience in Linux. I'm working on a remote Linux server without root privilege. After trying to install a software package by including the path variable to the `.bashrc`, I'm not  able to access any of my file in the working directory. I'm also not able to execute any command. Always getting an error message `-bash:  command not found`.

Whenever I login I'm getting a message:

```
-bash: export: `/opt/xcat/bin:/opt/xcat/sbin:/opt/xcat/share/xcat/tools:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/lpp/mmfs/bin:/usr/local/maui/sbin:/usr/local/maui/bin': not a valid identifier
```

Comment: Looks like there's an error in your `.bashrc`. Can you show us its contents?

Comment: You screwed up your attempt to set the path in your .bashrc, and you forgot to test it (by executing `bash -l`) before you logged out. Now you're screwed.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/94503/login-without-running-bash-profile-or-bashrc

Comment: @Biffen now im not able to open my .bashrc profile. Not sure how to show its content.

Comment: @beginner There's probably *some* way to get it. See Paul's comment above. Off the top of my head: `ssh <machine> sh -i` or `scp <machine>:~/.bashrc <file>`

Comment: Do you have a shell open on that machine? If so, you might be able to edit your .bashrc by specifying the full path to your editor, like `/usr/bin/vi .bashrc`